# Using CoffeeScript string interpolation inside a for loop

Tags: coffeescript

I am filling an html `<select>` list with `<option>` elements based on a blob of JSON data. I would like to tidy up my code by using string interpolation but I cannot get the values to substitute correctly.

Here is the code that works (no interpolation):

```
$list
.empty()
.append('<option value="' + item.Id + '">' + item.Name + '</option>' for item in data)
```

Here is how I would like to do things (does not work):

```
$list
.empty()
.append('<option value="#{item.Id}">#{item.Name}</option>' for item in data)
```

Here is an example of the JSON I am using:

```
[
  {"Id":"1","Name":"Client-1"},
  {"Id":"2","Name":"Client-2"}
]
```

The substitutions do not happen, instead I just get a list filled with the correct number of `#{item.Name}` strings.

Is it possible to use CoffeeScript string interpolation inside a for loop like this?

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for HTML Templating, which coffeescript does not have. If you're trying to avoid string concatenation, just build the element via jQuery methods instead of appending a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String interpolation only works with double-quoted strings, not apostrophe-quoted strings.

http://coffeescript.org/#strings

This should work:

```
$list
.empty()
.append("<option value=\"#{item.Id}\">#{item.Name}</option>" for item in data)
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. So is it best practice to use double-quoted strings throughout all of CoffeeScript? I am never sure what to use these days.

Comment: @biofractal: I single quote unless I need to double quote, that way a double quote indicates that there is code to look at rather than just a string literal. I do the same thing in all languages that have interpolation.

Comment: If you use `"""<option value="#{item.Id}">#{item.Name}</option>""" for item in data` you do not have to escape each double quote inside the string.